# How can I load a file in a libgdx project on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I´m trying to use the `Gdx.files.internal` to load a skin in my libgdx project. However I´m getting the following exception:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
```

I have the uiskin.json inside the assets folder on the android subproject. Can anyone tell me how to correctly specify the path?

This is a screenshot of the project structure:

[image]

Here's my skin file:

```
{
  com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: myFont.fnt } },
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
   default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font },
  },
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default:  {
      titleFont: default-font
     }
   }
}
```

And this is the complete stack:

```
03-06 16:20:49.785 16830-16919/com.mygdx.gdxhouse E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2645
                                                                    com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:97)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74)
                                                                        at com.mygdx.gdxhouse.GDXHouse.create(GDXHouse.java:20)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:290)
                                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
                                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
                                                                     Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:694)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:95)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74) 
                                                                        at com.mygdx.gdxhouse.GDXHouse.create(GDXHouse.java:20) 
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:290) 
                                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505) 
                                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240) 
                                                                     Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Font file not found: myfont.fnt
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$3.read(Skin.java:452)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$3.read(Skin.java:443)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:884)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:408)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:852)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.readNamedObjects(Skin.java:429)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:418)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:414)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:884)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:408)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:692)
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:95) 
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74) 
                                                                        at com.mygdx.gdxhouse.GDXHouse.create(GDXHouse.java:20) 
                                                                        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:290) 
                                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505) 
                                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Comment: This can be caused due to a Syntax Error in the .json file. Add the whole error stack to your question so it's easier to see what's the problem.

Comment: Thanks liga. I´ve added the corresponing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Font file not found: myfont.fnt`

The font is called `myFont.fnt`. Since the file system is case-sensitive, you need to either change the skin to point at `myFont.fnt` or change the file's name to `myfont.fnt`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem. I also had to add the uiskin.atlas file to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your .json is missing quotes. E.g.,

**Wrong:**
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: myFont.fnt } },

**Correct:**
"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont": { "default-font": { "file": "myFont.fnt" } },

Additionally, in the `TextButtonStyle` clause you have an extra comma:

**Wrong:**
default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font },

**Correct:**
"default": { "down": "default-round-down", "up": "default-round", "font": "default-font" }

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I´ve tried adding the quotes and I still get the same error. Also, in the docs of the libgdx library the examples of skin files do not have quotes, so I´m not sure if adding quotes is necessary:https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin

Comment: @PabloEstrada I found another syntax error. Please see my updated answer.